How to set up a local VPN-connected environment with a public IP address?
I’m trying to achieve a setup where my local machine functions like a VPS with a public IP address.
The idea is to use a service that provides an OpenVPN (or similar) configuration file, which I can use to connect my local machine to their network. Once connected, I’d like my machine to have a public IP address, effectively making it behave like a VPS.
Please note, I want all traffic and open ports (both TCP and UDP) on my local machine to be forwarded through this connection, not just HTTP/HTTPS traffic.
What kind of services should I look into to achieve this? Any guidance on potential providers or general approaches would be appreciated.
